# Ionic Select option and retrive its value on second page

Tags: angularjs, select, ionic-framework, dropdown

i am very new to ionic and angularjs. i am using ionic 1 and i want to get a value after make a selection from dropdown..after i select and click next button, the other page will show the name of item that i select.this is on first page. on the second page i want it display communication if i select it on 1st page. i know this is the wrong way..can help me?

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
<div class="input-label">
  Initiative A
</div>
<select>
    <option>Communication</option>
  <option>Customer</option>
    <option selected></option>
  </select>
```

Comment: How do you navigate to next page on "next" button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected option using ng-modal.

```
<select ng-modal="selectedValue">
  <option>Communication</option>
  <option>Customer</option>
  <option selected></option>
</select>
```

Now you will get the selected option on controller by $scope.selectedValue.

You can pass this value to next page using $rootScope or as stateParam.

In first controller,

```
.controller('myCtrl1',function($scope, $rootScope){      
      $rootScope.myValue = $scope.selectedValue;
 })
```

In second controller,

```
.controller('myCtrl2',function($scope, $rootScope){      
      $scope.selectedValue = $rootScope.myValue; 
})
```

You can display this value in second page HTML like {{selectedValue}}

Comment: what should i type in controller and second page? can u help me step by step if u dont mind. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Save the value in `$rootScope`

```
.controller('Ctrl_1',function($rootScope){      
          $rootScope.myValue= "communication(i.e, use ng-modal)"
})
```

and access it like this

```
.controller('Ctrl_2',function($rootScope){  
alert("what is my value? " + $rootScope.myValue);
})
```

Comment: i have try and the value still not visible in my second page. what should i do exactly?can u help me step by step if u dont mind. thanks

Comment: use exactly what I did, write first part of code in firstcontroller and second code in the nextpagecontroller